PdfRenderer.openPage is unexpectedy throwing a java.lang.IllegalStateException
According to the documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer#openPage(int)), IllegalStateException should only be thrown if PdfRenderer.close() is called before attempting to open a page, but I've stepped through in a debugger and confirmed that the renderer has not been closed before the call to openPage. Here's the full stack trace:
FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-3-thread-2
Process: com.example.my_app, PID: 11178
java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot load page
    at android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.nativeOpenPageAndGetSize(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.-$$Nest$smnativeOpenPageAndGetSize(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer$Page.<init>(PdfRenderer.java:315)
    at android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer$Page.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.openPage(PdfRenderer.java:233)
    at com.example.my_app.LoadedDocument.renderPage(LoadedDocument.kt:353)

95% of the time, my app works fine; the exception is only thrown if I tap on the screen to rapidly go through 20-30 pages in a short period of time. At first, I thought I might have been using too much memory, but I deallocate previously loaded page, and as the below profiler shows, I'm not even hitting 1GB of memory usage, so I don't believe it's that.

Here's how I'm using the method:
    private fun renderAndSavePage(pageNumber: Int) {
        pagesSemaphore.acquire()

        // Exit early if a previous call rendered this page.
        if (pages[pageNumber].width != EMPTY_BITMAP_WIDTH) {
            pagesSemaphore.release()
            return
        }

        // If, in the time between this function call and acquiring the semaphore,
        // the user has quickly switched pages beyond where this needs to be loaded,
        // skip loading this.
        if (abs(pageNumber - metadata.pageNo) > PAGE_BUFFER) {
            pagesSemaphore.release()
            return
        }

        // Open the page and save it to a bitmap.
        val page = renderer.openPage(pageNumber)
        val ratio = page.height.toFloat() / page.width.toFloat()
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            imagePixelWidth,
            (imagePixelWidth * ratio).toInt(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        )
        bitmap.eraseColor(Color.WHITE)
        page.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY)
        pages[pageNumber] = bitmap
        page.close()
        pagesSemaphore.release()
    }


You really need to show your code on how you render each page.

@Andrew edited to include that information

I think an IllegalStateException can also be caused if a page is already opened for rendering. You don't show enough code and how you setup the Semaphore if your number of permits is more than 1 and if this could be run in parallel and two calls to be made to render the same page. If the render is done in parallel then your Exit early test could easily cause a timing issue as there is some time before the bitmap array for an individual page gets assigned for a width that can be tested.

@Andrew Thanks for the suggestion! My Semaphore is initialized with 1 permit and doesn't ever go above that. I also tested, and if you try opening the same page twice, or try opening a second page with the first is still open, the error message is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current page not closed, not cannot load page.

In that case, the traceback also goes through throwIfPageOpened(PdfRenderer.java:279), not nativeOpenPageAndGetSize

Yes I did not know if the text of the IllegalStateException had changed over time but sometimes the docs are not great and I had looked at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/lollipop-release/graphics/java/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.java previously

This might help https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/lollipop-release/core/jni/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.cpp#102 might be the page number does not exist in the document, may be log the page number you are rendering in a try-catch to catch the error and it's associated page number.

What page number are you using as https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/pdfium/+/refs/heads/master/public/fpdfview.h#697 suggests that they start at zero for first page (not one)

@Andrew I was able to confirm that this behavior is caused by a malformed PDF, but I appreciate your help in identifying that as the root cause!

At first I thought it was happening randomly since it was triggering on multiple different pages on the pdf. But after opening the pdf in a different reader, it turns out that the pdf I was testing with happened to have multiple corrupted pages in it, and they exactly lined up with the ones that were causing the exception to get thrown in my app.
I'm not familiar enough the PDF specification to try to diagnose exactly how it is misformed, but at least I know that this specific exception means that the page is corrupted.
For anyone curious to look deeper into this, the specific pdf I was testing with can be found at https://www.lavarosso.com/Musica/tromba/Arban.pdf, and it's starting at page 312 where certain ones are corrupted; should be obvious exactly which ones are messed up.
Edit: I created an issue to have the documentation updated to indicate this as a possibility: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/386853931
